# Laravel - Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Object' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am currently trying to figure out why I get this error:

```
FatalThrowableError: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Object' not found in Operators.php line 23
```

This is the Operators.php controller from where the error is coming from:

```
public function getOperatorData()
{
    $api = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://www.space-track.org',
    'cookies' => true, 
    ]); $api->post('ajaxauth/login', [
      'form_params' => [
         'identity' => '#', 
         'password' => '#', 
     ],
    ]);
    $response = $api->get('basicspacedata/query/class/satcat/orderby/INTLDES%20desc/limit/1/metadata/false');
    $mydata = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
    $object = new Object();
    $object->intldes = $mydata->INTLDES;
    $object->satname = $mydata->SATNAME;
    $object->save();
    return view('pages/satellite-database', compact('object'));
}
```

The specific line from where the error comes from is:

```
$object = new Object();
```

The line shown above should be creating a new model for querying`in a blade file later on.

I am usually able to solve these (either I forgot the 'use' or something), but I have been unable to solve this error.

Comment: if you need the generic PHP object class use `new stdObject()` , `Object` is not a valid class name

Comment: @apokryfos I tried that but unfortunately it did not work. The error I get with that is `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\stdObject' not found`

Comment: Oops, I meant `\stdClass`

Comment: try using full namespace to class like `new \App\Object`

Comment: I managed to get rid of the error be changing it to `$object = new \stdClass();`, but now I have a `Trying to get property of non-object` error. I will see what I can do

Comment: What do you have in $mydata ?

Comment: @Rishi `$mydata = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());`. The code works when I remove anything starting with `$object`. I am guessung that is the problem

Comment: @D.777KLM if the contents are empty then `json_decode` will return an null, which itself is not an error but may cause the other errors.

Comment: @D.777KLM Where is Object.php file in your project directory?

Comment: @apokryfos Just checked - I have data in the JSON file.

Comment: @mokamoto12 I never used an Object.php file for my project. I am only using the controller to access my saved database variable and view in a blade file as $object.

Comment: just do a `dd($mydata)` to be sure

Comment: @apokryfos I can confirm that I get a JSON array with `dd($mydata)` Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/6qLVAjz.png

Comment: There's a discrepency here. You're getting an array (of objects) back but json_decode should be returning an object. Not sure what to make of that. Do a `dd($response->getBody()->getContents())` and inspect what the body contains, it's possible that it's being automatically decoded.

Comment: @apokryfos Just noticed the same thing. `dd($response->getBody()->getContents())` actually returns nothing. I think I did something wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem lay in the `$mydata = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());`.

Once I changed `$mydata` to `return`, I managed to make the JSON format properly and get the `$object` array to work.